# Wrap Content UILabel in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to make a cell that will have two UILabels at the same line.
Like this:

```
User Name: blablabla
```

Where `User Name` is the first UILabel and `blablabla` is the second UILabel.

I want the first UILabel to be wrap content and the second one to have its content extended until the super view's trailing.

I tried to look for an answer to my question around StackOverflow, but I could not find one. Does someone know how can I achieve that?

---

I want something just like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name:"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="bla bla bla"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

or like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="bla bla bla"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/first_label"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It seems, this is an android layout code...? Are you looking for iOS solution or Android?

Comment: An iOS solution. But it is easier to explain what I want with an Android .xml code.

Comment: Ohh..! So, it this helpful to you, or you need something else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317901/wrap-content-uilabel-in-xcode/49318364#49318364

Comment: Yeap, it did :D. But modifying another property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change content compression resistance priority

Look at these snapshots:

Labels with default `content compression resistance priority`

[image]

I changed `content compression resistance priority` for label `blablabla blablabla`, from `750` to `749`.

Result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Krunal. Content Compression Resistance Priority did not work for me. But Content Hugging Priority did :)

Comment: Both works vice-a-versa, Either you can change Horizontal Hugging priority or change compression priority

Answer (score 1):

- you can do this by : 
  yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following solution.

For first label.

1. Add top, left, bottom, width constraint.
2. Now set number of lines to 0 and `Autoshrink` to Minimum font size shown as below. You should set your required minimum font size.

[image]

For second label

1. Add top, left, bottom, right.
2. Now set number of lines to 0 and `Autoshrink` to Minimum font size shown as below. You should set your required minimum font size.

These changes will make first label's font autoshirnk upto your minimum font size. And will also make the second label to extent the content.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with defining the width of the first label? I really do not want to predefine it. It should be WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: Please elaborate your comment

Comment: no like android you can't do it you have to specify any one element's width or height to either fix or relative. Another will take remaining height  or width according to constraint you set.